# Access Virtual Smart Card In Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11, smartcard

I am trying to access smart card through web browser (only IE), on Windows 8.1, in Javascript. Given what I read on the web, this is possible using ActiveX, but I don't know what Application.Class is used to access the smart card readers, and then the smart card itself.

What ActiveX Object should I instanciate to access smart card readers ?

Is their an other way to open a connection with smart cards ?

(given my project's limits, I can not use winRT or create a JAVA, .NET or so web application)

Comment: You need to look at the API documentation provided by the smart card readers.  Do they provide COM objects you may be able to access etc?

Comment: I will have to interact with usb readers (different kinds of products) and the Virtual Smart Card of Windows